# template filter to trim any leading or trailing whitespace

Tags: django, django-template-filters

Is there a template filter in django that will trim any leading or trailing whitespace from the input text.

Something like: `{{ var.example|trim }}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it yourself

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def trim(value):
    return value.strip()
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#template-filters-that-expect-strings)

Comment: Using `{{ var.example.strip }}` is indeed simpler, however this solution here also has its use. For example it allows you to do `{% filter trim %}{% someothertag %}{% endfilter %}`, which is not otherwise possible.

Answer (score 91):

[Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables) allow you to access methods and properties by using the '.' syntax:

```
{{ var.example.strip }}
```

You can extend this by chaining other filters when you're dealing with HTML, e.g.:

```
{{ var.example.strip|safe|removetags:"p img" }}
```

Here we first remove any `<p>` and `<img>` tags, then tell Django it can safely render the rest of the content, which we have stripped of any whitespace.

Comment: It's not Django function, but Python's. It is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip . Documentation of Django template variables: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables

Comment: one comment - `removetags` filter is being removed as of django 1.10, so be carefull