# Strip content of spaces after truncatewords filter

Tags: python, django

Is there a way in django to strip the trailing spaces from a variable after it has been truncated using the truncate words filter?
I.e. I do this:

```
{{post.body|safe|truncatewords:65}}
```

And end up getting something like this:

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo ...

However I'd rather not have that trailing space. It should look like this:

Foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo...

Is there a built in way to do this - I couldn't find one - or do I just need to make a custom filter?

EDIT:

For the record, if anyone else is having this issue, you will need to write a custom truncate function. As I was going about this I realized that django is probably making the "..." the final index in an array and joining it with a blank space. You will never be able to get rid of this without writing a custom filter!

Here's my implementation of truncate that does not put a space in between the last word and the ...:

In my template:

```
{{post.body|truncate:65|safe}}
```

In my templatetags package this:

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def truncate(value,end):
    words = value.split()
    keep = words[0:end]
    keep[end-1] = keep[end-1]+"..."
    return " ".join(keep)
```

It works!
As you can see, it would have been easy to just make

```
keep[end] = "..."
```

Which is what I believe the truncatewords function probably does. But that doesn't look pretty because there will be white space before it when you join! So use this if you like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either create your own filter or directly call the strip method.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361240/template-filter-to-trim-any-leading-or-trailing-whitespace#answer-10361276) to create your own trim filter or this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361240/template-filter-to-trim-any-leading-or-trailing-whitespace#answer-12368885) to view an example of using the strip method.