# for loop adds extra new lines and whitespace

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-2.1

I have a queryset using which I want to display values of a certain field.

```
   {% for pm in paymentmethods %}
      {{pm.get_payment_method_display}}
   {% endfor %}
```

This works fine but it adds lots of extra space per `get_payment_method_display`.

This is how it ends up looking like:

[image]

How do i get rid of the extra white space and just show each item in a new line.

This is how my `pre` css class looks like:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */

}
```

Comment: Quite apart from anything else, do you *really* need to support 20-year-old browsers?

Comment: That `pre` css class is part of an effort to fix the whitespace problem.

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. But since you mention it, why do you need it in a pre? Wouldn't an unordered list be better?

Comment: I like the box around `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .strip to strip the white space. `{{ var.example.strip }}` Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361240/template-filter-to-trim-any-leading-or-trailing-whitespace) about trimming white space and tags.

Comment: tried that. it did not work. also tried whitespaces tag. didn't work either.